# Помогите ускорить запрос к MySQL с большим offset limit

Tags: mysql, dle

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше составить запрос к mysql для вывода новостей на DLE, чтобы максимально ускорить? по дефолту представлен следующий запрос:

```
SELECT p.id, p.autor, p.date, p.short_story, 
   CHAR_LENGTH(p.full_story) as full_story, 
   p.xfields, p.title, p.category, p.alt_name,
   p.comm_num, p.allow_comm, p.fixed, p.tags, 
   e.news_read, e.allow_rate, e.rating, e.vote_num, 
   e.votes, e.view_edit, e.editdate, e.editor, e.reason 
FROM dle_post p LEFT JOIN dle_post_extras e ON (p.id=e.news_id) 
WHERE approve=1 AND allow_main=1 AND date < '2017-05-18 14:23:53' 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 182208,48
```

С помощью него mysql отдает ответ за 3.1171 сек.
Я чуть чуть подкорректировал его и привел к такому виду:

```
SELECT p.id, p.autor, p.date, p.short_story, 
    CHAR_LENGTH(p.full_story) as full_story, 
    p.xfields, p.title, p.category, p.alt_name, 
    p.comm_num, p.allow_comm, p.fixed, p.tags, 
    e.news_read, e.allow_rate, e.rating, e.vote_num, 
    e.votes, e.view_edit, e.editdate, e.editor, e.reason 
FROM dle_post p LEFT JOIN dle_post_extras e ON (p.id=e.news_id) 
    JOIN ( SELECT id 
           FROM dle_post 
           WHERE approve=1 AND allow_main=1 
              AND date < '2017-05-18 14:23:53' 
           ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 182208,48 
         ) as t ON t.id = p.id
```

Данный запрос отрабатывает за 1.3736 сек.

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли еще как-то ускорить получение ответа?

Comment: В идеале надо бы где то запоминать стартовые даты для страниц и избегать таких offset

Comment: Что показывает `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/POTJiRu.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в сортировку поле `dle_post.id` и передавайте в запрос `dle_post.id` и `dle_post.date` из последней строки предыдущей выборки. Будет такой запрос:

```
SELECT p.id, p.autor, p.date, p.short_story, 
   CHAR_LENGTH(p.full_story) as full_story, 
   p.xfields, p.title, p.category, p.alt_name,
   p.comm_num, p.allow_comm, p.fixed, p.tags, 
   e.news_read, e.allow_rate, e.rating, e.vote_num, 
   e.votes, e.view_edit, e.editdate, e.editor, e.reason 
FROM dle_post p
LEFT JOIN dle_post_extras e ON (p.id=e.news_id) 
WHERE approve=1
      AND allow_main=1
      AND (p.date < @last_date
           OR
           (p.date = @last_date
            AND p.id = @last_id))
ORDER BY date DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 48;
```